# ¿Por qué la respuesta de una request en una API devuelve valores del tipo u'value'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, rest

En este momento me he topado con algo nuevo en mis apis rest al tratar de consumirlas.
Cuando envio una peticion por post, al obtener la información de mi request me obtiene lo siguiente:

```
{u'value': u'hola como estamos'}
```

¿A que se debe la "u"?

Ya verifiqué que los valores que les envío sean un JSON.

La API esta desarrollada con Python y Falcon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la `u` no aparece en el contenido http de los mensajes, sino una vez recibido en el servidor python, parseado el json para generar un diccionario python, e impreso ese diccionario para depuración.

La `u` delante de una cadena es sintaxis usada por python 2 para especificar que la cadena es Unicode, y diferenciarla así de las cadenas "normales" que son meras secuencias de bytes sin codificación conocida. Python3, al usar de forma nativa cadenas unicode no necesita ya esa `u`.

En definitiva es un "artefacto" mostrado por python cuando le pides imprimir la forma representable de un objeto, pero que no deberia afectar al funcionamiento del programa ya que desaparece al codificar la cadena en json.

Si no fuera el caso, sino que efectivamente estas `u` te aparecen en el json que se transmite por http, sería que estás generando mal ese json (por ejemplo, estás simplemente volcando a cadenas diccionarios python, en lugar de usar el módulo `json` para hacer as conversiones). En ese caso sería necesario ver tu código para más detalles.